# SQL order but first all rows with userId

Tags: sql

I have got table with orders and there is Identity column Id, UserId and Value.

I would like to write query which return records ordered by Value but ensure that first n rows are the rows of the currently logged in user.

Is it possible ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What's the Value column contains?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you know the user ID prior to executing the query, try using a case statement

```
SELECT Id, UserId, Value,
    CASE UserId WHEN :userId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS UserPriority
ORDER BY UserPriority DESC, Value ASC
```

substituting `:userId` for your known user ID

Comment: @gruber I missed the `END` in the `CASE` clause. Fixed by Sean (thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution specific to SQL Server

```
declare @userid int = x
declare @n int = y  

;with a as (
  select
    row_number() over ( partition by userid order by value) as user_seq,
    case 
      when userid = @userid then 1 
      else 0 
    end as is_user,
    *
  from orders
), b as (
  select
    case 
      when is_user = 1 and user_seq <= @n then 1 
      else 0 
    end as sort_first,
    a.* 
  from a
)
select * from b
order by sort_first desc, value
```

Answer (score -1):

You could write something as such.

```
select * from orders,users where users.id = order.userid and user.loggedin = true

union

select * from orders,users where users.id = order.userid and user.loggedin <> true
```

Comment: When performing a union the records of the first query are always listed first. So this means the logged in user will show up first in the list and the not logged in user will show second. You do not always need order by clause to order records.

Comment: The order of results returned from a `UNION` (or even a `UNION ALL`) are not well defined, and any observed orderings should not be relied on. That being said, most common implementations of `UNION` I'm aware of will end up sorting all of the result rows as a single group, so this answer is even less likely to be correct. The *only* correct way to determine the order of results in an SQL query is to find a way to express that ordering in an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Should be trivial to add ordering field to the union query. Add 0 to the first and 1 to the second query. Do use "union all" when you can be sure no duplicate records exist or duplicates do not matter.